# Error on ftp-file close operation

Tags: php, file, ftp

I'm using php to access file by ftp.
My file read function is:

```
function _rfile ($file = null) {
        if ( is_readable($file) ) {
            if ( !($fh = fopen($file, 'r')) ) return false;
            $data = fread($fh, filesize($file));
            fclose($fh);
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I am getting an error on file close operation in this function with one of my ftp host.

error:

> fclose(): FTP server error 550:550 The specified network name is no
>   longer available.

This function worked fine for some other ftp host's.

Could smb advice a solution?

Comment: I'd ignore this error, since it's happening after you've successfully read the data. Use `@fclose($fh)`.

Comment: Yup, that's right. But I want to know the cause of this error.

Comment: Is it a Windows server? Haven't found any detailed explanations in google, but they all seem to point to an issue in Windows servers.

Comment: If you have a local FTP server, try to use this function on it and see if it returns an error.

Comment: Also if you have an antivirus program try to disable it and see if the error gets triggered. Sources: [Link 1](http://serverfault.com/a/151910), [Link 2](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f138/solved-the-specified-network-file-name-is-no-longer-available-184430.html).

Comment: @Barmar  Yes, I think may be the problem is with the windows server.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV I have checked it with a linux server and works fine. Also I am running on linux, so its not the problem with the antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

It may due to the access permission settings.

Please look at this link.  http://forums.iis.net/t/1107644.aspx

Comment: I can do almost all operations except fclose().